# Most efficient way to get all non-zero storage locations for a smart contract?

Tags: web3js, storage, web3.py, get-storage-at

I'm looking at a `mainnet` smart contract and want to figure out all storage positions/slots where the storage has a non-zero value.

Is there a way to do this other than replaying and tracing all storage write/`SSTORE` operations during all contract transactions involving this contract?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ethereum decompiler like https://github.com/palkeo/panoramix  to find these slots for you.

I came up against this issue recently. Normally storage slots are stored sequentially, but for proxy contracts that follow "Transparent Upgradble Proxy pattern", the storage slots are actually randomized to prevent storage clashes between the proxy and implementation contracts.

```
from panoramix.decompiler import decompile_address
contract = "0x989aeb4d175e16225e39e87d0d97a3360524ad80"
decoded = decompile_address(contract)
data = decoded.json
for storage_def in data["stor_defs"]:
    print(storage_def)
```

Alternatively, Etherscan has a handy decompile feature for smart contracts. This uses panoramix under the hood.[image]

Hope this helps. Even if two years late :P

Comment: Decompilation will help with storage layout but the question refers to filled storage slots. For that, we need to look at archive data.